# Retrofit: sending POST request

Tags: java, android, retrofit

This is declaration of my POST request:

```
@POST("/api/geo/getLoc")
    public void getFriendsLocation(@Field("Id") int Id, @Field("Number") String Number, @Field("FriendNumber") String FriendNumber, Callback<JsonElement> response);
```

This is how i try to send and handle this request:

```
 String ENDPOINT = "http://52.88.**.***";
 FriendModel ff = new FriendModel();
        ff.setFriendNumber("380935275259");
        ff.setId(516);
        ff.setNumber("380936831127");
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
                .build();
        WayfAPI api = adapter.create(WayfAPI.class);
        api.getFriendsLocation(ff.getId(), ff.getNumber(), ff.getFriendNumber(), new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void success(JsonElement jsonElement, Response response) {
                String strObj = jsonElement.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        });
```

Error:

```
 retrofit.RetrofitError: WayfAPI.getFriendsLocation: @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1)
```

What's wrong with my request ?

Comment: Feels very odd that a method such as retreiving locations of friends is marked as POST and not GET. Are you sure the server is considering this method as POST?

Comment: @Hasslarn i know that name of this method a little bit incorrect, but i'm sure that that POST method

Comment: Have you checked if the failure method is getting called? That might give you information on what went wrong, such as a HTTP code from the server.

Comment: @Hasslarn i tried to add breakpoint in successfull and failure section in Callback, but nothing happens. It looks like it can't sending request, becouse something wrong with my code.

Comment: Breakpoint might not work too well in the failure method because there is no code lines to break on.  Try putting `error.printStackTrace();` in your `failure` method and see what you see in the log

Comment: You do have the internet permission in your android manifest right? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @iagreen Thank you for your answer, now i can see error in console. But i still can't understand what's wrong with my code
Error: getFriendsLocation: @ Field parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1)

Comment: @Hasslarn no, i wrote above which error it throw to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you forget `@FormUrlEncoded` annotation in your method declaration. It should be like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/geo/getLoc")
public void getFriendsLocation(@Field("Id") int Id, @Field("Number") String Number, @Field("FriendNumber") String FriendNumber, Callback<JsonElement> response);
```

Comment: Thank you, thats working. I have response with code 200, but i need in JSON string in response, but my strObject = "".
Request is exactly correct. What's can be wrong ?

Comment: That's kind of another question, it seems I answered main question correctly. It depends on data format your receiving on response. You should define POJO object which describes JSON data in response, and use this object in your Callback interface.